# Copy images from CSS url(…) during Rollup / Bili build

Tags: css, vue.js, rollup

I am using bili and rollup-plugin-vue 1 to compile a Vue component library. @rollup/plugin-url 3 handles require calls to image files and copies them to the dist/ folder.

Expected result (works with  and  in SFC):
Within Vue SFC templates, my setup transforms  and require('./foo.jpg') correctly and will generate dist/foo.jpg and a correct path somewhere in the output JS.

However, this technique does not process CSS in SFCs (e.g. background-image: url('./foo.jpg')). I have tried postcss-url without success. It seems that @vue/component-compiler-utils prevents postcss-url from receiving correct output paths.

How can I get Rollup to copy assets that are referenced from CSS over to my destination folder, and adjust the URLs in the output CSS accordingly? Is anyone building Vue component libraries with Rollup these days?

Comment: Same question here, I cannot find a way to copy assets also with svelte...
The only one i Found is a postcss plugin that is able to process images but only if you reference css/sass/less from js..